# Ender 3 v2 Print not consistent

Tags: creality-ender-3, underextrusion, filament-jam

I just got my first 3D printer (Ender 3 V2) 3 days ago and at first it was printing fine but yesterday it started painting dotted lines. I heard it could be a clog so I changed the Nozzle after trying to clean it (Didn't fix it). Then I replaced the Bowden tubes and made sure there was no filament jammed in the hot piece. After doing this the printer sometimes prints straight solid lines but most of the time either no filament comes out or it is dotted. What can this be and how can I fix it? I think it got clogged in the first place because the nozzle was too close to the plate so what would be a good Z index while printing? Thanks

Comment: Please add a photo and look into the extruder, does it have enough tension on the filament? (look at the spring loaded lever)